# How to pass multiple updates to different records in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Laravel allows to insert multiple rows passing as array of array rows to be inserted

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#inserts

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0] 
]);
```

Is there any alternative to do the same with update?

```
DB::table('users')->update[
    [update to record 1],
    [update to record 2]
];
```

Comment: Nope, unless its actually a mass update query (e.g. update all records where .... to ...) cant be done. You might try a `DB::insert("replace into ...")` if you're using mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can use a specific query like in the following example.

suppose we have a structure like this:

```
+----+----------+-------------+---------+
| id | username | club        | country |
+----+----------+-------------+---------+
|  2 | Messi    | Barca       | Arg     |
|  3 | Ronaldo  | Juventus    | Por     |
|  4 | Salah    | Liverpool   | Egy     |
+----+----------+-------------+---------+
```

and we want update all rows and columns in one query.

we can use the following instructions:

```
 $table = 'players';// table name

 // values to update
 $values = [['id' => '2','club' =>'Barca',  'country' => 'Argentina'],
            ['id' => '3','club' =>'Man Utd','country' => 'Portugal'],
            ['id' => '4','club' =>'Chelsea','country' => 'Egypte']];


 $cases = [];
 $ids = [];
 $param1 = []; // for the first column
 $param2 = []; // for the Seconde column
 $params = []; // for merging all columns

 foreach ($values as $value) {

     $value=(object)$value;
     $id = (int) $value->id;
     $cases[] = "WHEN {$id} then ?";
     $param1[] =$value->club;
     $param2[] =$value->country;
     $ids[] = $id;
 }

 $params=array_merge($param1,$param2);

 $ids = implode(',', $ids);
 $cases = implode(' ', $cases);    

\DB::update("UPDATE `{$table}` 
             SET `club`    = CASE `id` {$cases} END ,
                 `country` = CASE `id` {$cases} END 
             WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $params);
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use the [newQuery](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_newQuery) method

```
$rows = [
    [id => '1', 'email' => 'foo@bar'], 
    [/*...*/]
];

$query = DB::table('users');

foreach(var $i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++) {

    if($i > 0) {
        $query->newQuery();
    }

    $query->where('id', $rows[$i]['id'])
          ->update(['email' => $rows[$i]['email'];

}
```

That may work (not tested)

Comment: @omixam what/how many columns should go in your where clause? Can you describe the nature of the update?

Comment: Like a mass update, but one condition affect only one row. If I have 20 rows I need one condition to each row.

Comment: @omixam Edited answer

Comment: No, because every time you call update Laravel execute against DB.